# Trying to get data with ember and django rest framework

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework

I have installed Ember Django Adapter(EDA) and I have followed the tutorial and in the template everything is ok but I'm not getting data from my api... but when my model its connect to the api I get the following warning in the console.

```
WARNING: Encountered "articles" in payload, but no model was found for model name "article" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:articles:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("articles"))
```

This is my code:

> app/application/serializer.js

```
import DRFSerializer from '../serializers/drf';

export default DRFSerializer.extend({
});
```

> app/application/adapter.js

```
import DRFAdapter from '../adapters/drf';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DRFAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin , {
  authorizer: 'authorizer:django'
});
```

> app/router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment'; 

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() { 
  this.route('index'); 
});

export default Router;
```

> app/models/articles.js

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  body: attr('string')
});
```

> app/index/route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('articles'); 
  }
});
```

> app/index/template.hbs

```
{{#each model as |article|}}
    <article class="listing">
      <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
    </article>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use singular words when naming models, so change your model file to "article.js" and also change in route.js file  to `this.get('store').findAll('article');`